# Can I use Swashbuckle with multiple documents that are not related to endpoints?

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I'm building an ASP.NET Core Web API, using Swashbuckle to generate a swagger doc page. I've used the Info object to customize the description, but I'm wondering if Swashbuckle supports adding other documents. For example, architecture documents, sample applications, etc. More than I want to put into the description. I know that I can have links in the Into.Description that can point to other pages, but I was hoping to reuse the formatting and visual of the swagger page, so it looks about the same.

Does Swashbuckle support additional pages link this?

Answer (score 1):

Swashbuckle is designed to generate a swagger document (OAS 2.0) for your WebApi, and that swagger doc is limited by that Specification:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md

Another limitation is the UI, Swashbuckle uses [Swagger-UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) that is separate project, it does offer some customization but I'm afraid is not what you are looking for:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#documentation

Swashbuckle has options to inject assets and customize the landing page:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#inject-custom-css

The good thing is that both Swashbuckle & Swagger-UI are Open Source so if you need to make changes to the core functionality you can!

Answer (score 0):

You can inject javascript files into the swagger UI. You can then use this js to insert links to other pages. These other pages can add references to the CSS files for the default swagger UI so that they take on some of the look and feel of the swagger UI.